# Visual Studio in Ubuntu Errors

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine

How can I install the latest Visual Studio beta in Ubuntu through wine?  It's so frustrating.  I just want C# bash scripting.  I get many errors.

Has anyone had success?

Comment: Have you tried https://code.visualstudio.com? See if it fits your requirements.

Comment: Wouldn't mono be a better choice for Linux?

Answer (score 1):

Oh carp.  You can't.  I saw the winedb.

Answer (score 1):

Check out MonoDevelop. MonoDevelop is an IDE focused on development with Mono and .Net frameworks.
Most people would say Visual Studio is better than MonoDevelop, though you can't get Visual Studio to run under linux, as much as i know.